# Firebase Functions: setup Admin Sdk without service-account.json file

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy my functions on firebase **without** needing to add `service-account.json` file to my project. This gives me the following error randomly on some functions while deploying:

> Error in the build environment

The solution I'm using is given in [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_the_sdk) to use

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

And if the deploy is successful for all the functions using the above initialization, then it fails when I try to mint a custom token in m y function using admin sdk with following error:

```
Error: createCustomToken() requires a certificate with "private_key" set.
    at FirebaseAuthError.Error (native)
    at FirebaseAuthError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:39:28)
    at FirebaseAuthError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:85:28)
```

Is there any problem with using this solution? Or do we need to include the service-account.json file if we need to mint custom token?

Comment: Hi Umar, using the default auth `admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)`  should work and the private credentials json file isn't required. Could it be that you're initialising the firebase app more than once? From my experience that could cause deployment issues. Only a single instance of the firebase app should be initiated for all your functions.

Comment: I tried with downgrading version of functions and admin library now they are working fine.

Comment: I thnik the issue is with the newer version of library

Comment: Hi the deployment is successful but the above error while minting custom token is still present, when function is triggered it shows the same error that private key is required.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and there is a way to bypass having an explicit json file if you have few environment variables.

Initialize it like this :

```
 admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    clientEmail: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
    privateKey: process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY?.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
    }),
  })
```

the last .replace is required to convert the key to how firebase accepts.

Source of my answer is [this.](https://www.benmvp.com/blog/initializing-firebase-admin-node-sdk-env-vars/)

Comment: This has become outdated

Answer (score -1):

From the [firebase admin node js docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens):

> Warning: Custom token creation works only when the SDK is authenticated with a service account (certificate) credential.

Seems you’ll have to use an explicit JSON auth to mint a token in the function.